# 'An engagement tablet' -- What is it?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In a story by Denton Welch I came across this fragment:

"*... and playing with the scent bottles, matchboxes and **engagement tablets** of old cracked ivory-the cracks were black, like my nails when I was sent to scrub them*". [Denton Welch, 'The Trout Stream']

What are "engagement tablets"? I can guess it's something small, ivory-colored, with cracks. Engagement ring boxes, perhaps? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found [this](https://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O113661/engagement-tablets-bury-freres/engagement-tablets-bury-fr%C3%A8res/) online. It appears to be an elaborate pocket book with an ivory page for each month. Presumably you could write down your engagements (appointments) for that month in pencil and wipe the page clean for re-use when the month was over.

Comment: Many thanks, Kate! It remains to find an equivalent in my language.

Comment: @DmitryAcemonte The modern term for the equivalent would be "diary, datebook, daybook, appointment book, planner or agenda" Check the "Languages" section of the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diary_(stationery)) (lower left of desktop site/near top of mobile site) for foreign language equivalents.

Comment: @R.M. - Don't forget that the passage the OP is asking about describes an antique object made of ivory, not a modern pocket diary!

Comment: @KateBunting That seems to be a fancy holder for the book.

Comment: Kind of like a fancy looseleaf binder.

Comment: @Barmar - The description says "ivory tablets in a tortoiseshell cover". It's my impression they are wipe-clean sheets of ivory.

Comment: To avoid confusion: that's a "pocket book" as in a book that one may keep in one's pocket, not a [pocketbook](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pocketbook) as in US-speak for "handbag".

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, so it's like a whiteboard!

Comment: Many thanks, my friends!